# Averaging of several values

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have a dataset (df3) with five columns x, y, r, g and b, although I only need to work with x, y and r. I want to find the average of all the consecutive rows in which the value of r is equal and store it in a database (df_final). To do this, I have generated a code that stores all the values in which r is equal to the one in previous row in a temporary database (df_inter), to later store the average of all the values in the final database (df_final). The code is this one:

```py
d = {'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'y':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],'r':[2,2,2,1,1,3,2]}
df3 = pd.Dataframe(data=d)
for i in range(len(df3)):
  if df3.iloc[i,3] == df3.iloc[i-1,3]:
    df_inter = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y', 'r'])
    df_inter.append(df3.iloc[i,1],df3.iloc[i,2],df3.iloc[i,3])
    df_inter.to_csv(f'Resultados/df_inter.csv', index=False, sep=',')
  else:
    df_final.append(df_inter['x'].mean(),df_inter['y'].mean(),df_inter['r'].mean())
    del [[df_inter]]
    gc.collect()
    df_inter=pd.DataFrame()
    df_inter = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y', 'r'])
    df_inter.append(df3.iloc[i,1],df3.iloc[i,2],df3.iloc[i,3])
    df_final.to_csv(f'Resultados/df_final.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```

The objective is from a dataset for example like this:

| x | y | r |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 |

Get something like this:

| x | y | r |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 4.5 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 |

Nevertheless, when I execute the code I get this error message:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

I'm not sure what the problem is or even if there is a code more efficient for the purpose. Please, I would be grateful if you could help me. Thank you in advance.

Irene

---

I solved it. The right code for my purpose would be:

```py
d = {'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'y':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],'r':[2,2,2,1,1,3,2]}
df3 = pd.Dataframe(data=d)
df_inter = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y', 'r'])
df_final = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y','r'])

for i in df3.index.values:
  if df3.iloc[i,2] == df3.iloc[i-1,2]:
    df_inter = df_inter.append({'x':df3.iloc[i,0],'y':df3.iloc[i,1],'r':df3.iloc[i,2]}, ignore_index=True)
  else:
    df_final = df_final.append({'x':df_inter['x'].mean(),'y':df_inter['y'].mean(),'r':df_inter['r'].mean()}, ignore_index=True)
    df_inter = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y', 'r'])
    df_inter = df_inter.append({'x':df3.iloc[i,0],'y':df3.iloc[i,1],'r':df3.iloc[i,2]}, ignore_index=True)

df_final = df_final.append({'x':df_inter['x'].mean(),'y':df_inter['y'].mean(),'r':df_inter['r'].mean()}, ignore_index=True)
df_final.to_csv(f'Resultados/df_final.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```

Comment: It may make sense to provide a reproducible example of your starting df, and then provide what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Why `del [[df_inter]]` and `gc.collect()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to the end of the dataframe using

```py
df_inter = df_inter.append({'x':df3.iloc[i,1],'y':df3.iloc[i,2],'r':df3.iloc[i,3]}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some knowledge of `SQL`, it can be intuitively done using `sqldf` and `pandas`:

```
import sqldf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"class":[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1],"value":[10,10,12,11,15,17,98,23,22,0]})

averages = sqldf.run("""
                     SELECT class,AVG(value)
                     FROM df
                     GROUP BY class
""")
```

The output being:

```
    class  AVG(value)

0      1        26.0
1      2        17.6
```

Is that what you are looking for ?